# Replace string with another one and vice versa

Tags: sed, grep

I have a folder structure like below:

```
a/b/sample.txt
c/d/e/sample1.txt
```

Both sample and sample file contains the sentence `My name is Debojyoti`

```
e/f/sample2.txt
g/h/i/sample3.txt
```

Both sample2 and sample3 file contains the sentence `My name is George`

Now I want to replace `George` with `Debojyoti` and `Debojyoti` with `George`

Any unix shell script can do this without hardcoding folder name.

Comment: I don't see any question. What command did you try and what is the problem?

Comment: I tried with : grep -rl .| xargs sed -i 's/Debojyoti/George/g'... but it is converting  all Debojyoti with George. But now I Not able to convert George to Debojyoti only for those files.

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system, you could do something like:

```
grep -rlZ -e Debojyoti -e George . |
  xargs -r0 sed -i '
    s/Debojyoti/\n/g
    s/George/Debojyoti/g
    s/\n/George/g'
```

`grep` lists the files that contain at least one of the two strings NUL-delimited.

`xargs` passes that list to `sed -i` for in-place editing.

`sed` processes the files one line at a time. For each line, all occurrences of `Debojyoti` are first replaced with a newline character (which is otherwise guaranteed not to occur in the *contents* of the lines), then `George` occurrences are replaced with `Debojyoti`. Then the newlines (which were the `Debojyoti`s originally) are replaced with `George`.

Instead of GNU `sed`, you could also use `perl` as:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(G)eorge|Debojyoti/$1 ? "Debojyoti" : "George"/ge'
```